# Proper way to update state through a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm very new to React-native but my question is: I want to know how to update states with a function. I previously did it through

```
onChangeText = {(text) => this.setState({ FirstName: text })}
```

on a `TextInput` component, but I replaced this with a function that helps me validate text input. I decided I want to store the states after a `onPress` action.

This is the class

```
class NameScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { FirstName: "", 
                       FirstNameValidate:false,
                       LastName: "", 
                       LastNameValidate:false,
                       PreferredName: "",
                       flag:false }
}
```

and here is the part of the render call

```
<TextInput 
  style={styles.nameScreen} 
  placeholder='Last Name'  
  returnKeyType= "next" 
  underlineColorAndroid={LastNameValidate? 'black': 'red'} 
  placeholderTextColor='rgba(0,0,0,.3)' 
  onChangeText={(text) => this.validate(text,'Last Name')}
   />

<TouchableOpacity 
  style={styles.YellowButtonContainer} 
  onPress= {() => this.RequiredFields("Name")}>
```

I want to update the states in the `this.RequiredFields("Name")` but I'm not too sure how to update these state

Here is the function

```
RequiredFields = (type) => 
{
  if(type == "Name"){
    navigateFirstNext = this.props.onPress;

    if(!this.state.FirstNameValidate || !this.state.LastNameValidate)
    {
      console.log("not")
      Alert.alert(
        "Please fill out al the required fields",
        null,
        [
          { text: "Okay", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      );
    }
    else
    {
      this.props.onChangeText = (text) => this.setState({ FirstName: text })
      this.props.onChangeText = (text) => this.setState({ LastName: text })
      navigateFirstNext = this.props.navigation.navigate('PhoneAndEmailScreen');

    }
}
}
```

I hope this make sense. let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: As you are accessing `props` in `RequiredFields` function like `this.props.onChangeText`, so post your parent component also.

Comment: im sorry the parent component to which child ?

Comment: For `NameScreen` component.

Comment: i thought this was the parent component . would the parent be the one that that navigates to this NameScreen ?

Comment: If this is the parent only, then how can you access `this.props.onChangeText`?